# Find index of substring within string from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe with two columns (and alot of rows), one column is the full sequence the other `contains a sub sequence.`

I want to find the index of where the sub sequence starts within the full sequence and add this as a another column:

I have tried this:

```
df["start"] = df.sequence.index(df.sub_sequence)
```

But this returns: `TypeError: 'RangeIndex' object is not callable`

What am i doing wrong?

Heres the df and the df i wish to end up with:

**Sample dataframe:**

```
import pandas as pd 

data = {"sequence": ["abcde","fghij","klmno"], "sub_sequence": ["cde", "gh", "no"]}    
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['sequence','sub_sequence'])

  sequence sub_sequence
0    abcde          cde
1    fghij           gh
2    klmno           no
```

---

**Expected result:**

```
data2 = {"sequence": ["abcde","fghij","klmno"], "sub_sequence": ["cde", "gh", "no"], "start": [2,1,3]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame (data2, columns = ['sequence','sub_sequence','start'])

  sequence sub_sequence  start
0    abcde          cde      2
1    fghij           gh      1
2    klmno           no      3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`str.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) in a list comprehension:

```
df['start'] = [seq.index(sub) for seq, sub in zip(df['sequence'], df['sub_sequence'])]
```

OR Use [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) along `axis=1` + [`str.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index):

```
df['start'] = df[['sequence', 'sub_sequence']].apply(lambda s: str.index(*s), axis=1)
```

Result:

```
  sequence sub_sequence  start
0    abcde          cde      2
1    fghij           gh      1
2    klmno           no      3
```